# How do we allow multiple selections for a single field in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We needed to have multiple values selection for a custom entity `Tagging`. Hence, [we successfully configured a many-to-many relationship](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2015/02/microsoft-dynamics-crm-customization-multi-value-selection/) between `Project` and `Tagging` entities:

[image: m to m relationship between Project and Tagging entities]

However, for this entity `Tagging`, we're unable to select multiple values in `Project` form:

[image: You can select only 1 row]

Any option on server side `C#` or `js` is fine.

How do we allow multiple selections for a single field in Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible out of the box (or) using C# (or) using JS as many to many in the background uses a intersect table to hold data. Any related `Tagging` entities will therefore show up under the record's sub navigation.

Very good workaround would be to use a html web resource prompt and get the selections from the user (using a custom multi-select control) or checkboxes. You can then use [CRM Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx) to pass the data to a custom workflow activity which would then associate the `Project` with the `Tagging` entity.

You could also write the selected values to a new field on the form as a comma delimited text and wire up a plugin on change of the field to create/update/delete related `Tagging` entities.

Use [Associate/Disassociate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309247.aspx) to associate projects and tagging records.